# How to link and filter data from 3 tables in Django orm

Tags: python, django, orm

I want to filter posts (beer) for which the user has not yet voted. To do this, I need to combine posts with a rating table and a help table where there is a user.
Example tables raiting in db
*https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MkL4IVtviIcPo7XFptoybPthNyO4dUp_/view?usp=sharing*
My model post

```
class Beerpost(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, editable=False)
    title = models.CharField("Назва", max_length=160)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=160, unique=True)
    img = ProcessedImageField(upload_to='static/img/%Y/%m/%d/%H/%M/%S/', processors = [ResizeToFit(150, 385)], format='JPEG', options={'quality': 90})    
    type_beer = models.ForeignKey(
        Type,
        verbose_name="Тип пива",
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True, default=1)
    volume = models.ForeignKey(Vol, verbose_name="Об'єм л.", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, default=3)
    price_limit = models.ForeignKey(Price, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Орієнтовна ціна', default=4)   
    country = models.ForeignKey(Country, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Країна', default=3)
    created = models.DateTimeField("Дата створення", auto_now_add=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)
    ratings = GenericRelation(Rating, related_query_name='foos')
    favorite = models.BooleanField(default=False, editable=False)
    users_reaction_favorite = models.ManyToManyField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, blank=True, related_name="users_reaction_favorite", editable=False)
```

I try this

```
all_beer = Beerpost.objects.all()
user_table = UserRating.objects.filter(user_id = pk)
join_user_table = user_table.select_related()
```

But I don't know how combine this 3 queries. Pleace help me, I three days can't solve this problem( Please help me, I three days can't solve this problem( or recommend me some others solution.

Comment: Can you share the (relevant parts of the) `Rating` model?

Answer (score 2):

You can query with:

```
Beerpost.objects.exclude(ratings__user=user)
```

with *`user`* the user object for which you want to obtain `Beerpost` objects where `user` is *not* part of the `ratings`.

Comment: I try 
`Beerpost.objects.exclude(ratings__user=request.user.id)`
but I get 
`FieldError at /profile/user/1/
Related Field got invalid lookup: user`  and thanks for reccomendation :)

Comment: @Serg: you did not define a `ForeignKey` to the user model in your `Rating` model? If it only has a `user_id` (I would really advice to use a `ForeignKey`), it is `ratings__user_id=user_id` (with `user_id` the id of that user)

Comment: I use django star_ratings module, his model described here: (https://github.com/wildfish/django-star-ratings/blob/develop/star_ratings/models.py) but I dont understand how it organize.

Comment: @Serg: what if you replace the `ratings = GenericRelation(Rating, related_query_name='foos')` with `ratings = GenericRelation(UserRating, related_query_name='foos')`, or even `ratings = ForeignKey(UserRating, related_query_name='foos')`?

Comment: I tried 
`Beerpost.objects.exclude(ratings__user_id=1)` and result:
`FieldDoesNotExist at /profile/user/1/
UserRating has no field named 'object_id'`
Need join raiting table

Comment: @Serg: `object_id`? Did you by any chance wrote `object_id` instead of `user_id`?

Comment: No, I wrote user_id, but possibly because posts related to rating via post id I get this error

Comment: @Serg: does the error says "possible options are ..."?

Comment: Sorry but I dont understand what you mean :( It's my error list: (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1eBhzHBEGZX4V_xETBBuDioAbNbs1jKYt/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @Serg: did you cahnge your `ratings` to `ratings = ForeignKey(UserRating, ...)`?

Comment: Yes I did this
I wrote `ratings = GenericRelation(UserRating, related_query_name='foos')` in my model Beerpost

Comment: @Serg: what if you replace `GenericRelation` with `ForeignKey`?

Comment: I get 
`ratings = ForeignKey(UserRating, related_query_name='foos')
NameError: name 'ForeignKey' is not defined
`

Comment: @Serg: you need to import this: `from django.db.models import ForeignKey`.

Comment: I broke my site)) `ProgrammingError at /profile/user/1/
column beerpost_beerpost.ratings_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...erpost"."created", "beerpost_beerpost"."updated", "beerpost_...`

Comment: Minus this method that I have some data from users. Therefore I need something that don't change my model. I think ideally consistent  filtration, but I don't know how it do. But thanks a lot for your spend time on my problem.

Comment: @Serg: then it is a `ManyToManyField`. You should then make proper migrations, etc.

Comment: Ok, I'll try this.

Comment: It's worked!!! I get query what I want, thanks you a lot, but now have problem with templates )) (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Q3B9mDInqpFnSBoWn3Daga-yhEYnwkpS/view?usp=sharing) But I try do it.

Comment: @Serg: you probably still need to make migrations, and migrate your database.